# Shopware v5: how to create custom widgets?

Tags: plugins, widget, shopware

The lack of English documentation is one of the major obstacles non German speaking developers face when dealing with Shopware development.

I was searching for documentation on how to create a widget, integrate it on my plugin and allow admins to include it on any product pages.. However i couldn't find any track except  this non working example: 
http://community.shopware.com/Eigene-Einkaufswelten-Elemente-erstellen_detail_1459.html
The provided example plugin: `Vimeo Widget Example Plugin` [doesn't work](https://github.com/shopware/devdocs/issues/110) on Shopware v5.

Is it even possible withing Shopware "ecosystem" to offer this customized widgets for admins; where they can choose in which part of their theme they want the widget to show? Or must they hard code the snippet that calls the widget inside their theme templates?

In Magento it is possible to create such widgets and admins can easily choose in which part of their theme (custom or default themes) they want the widget to appear.

In Prestashop they offer some kind of hooks, the same for WordPress.. What about Shopware?

Comment: In Shopware a Widget is only for the Shopping Worlds.
You could use a Item free text field in your product detail pages.

http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1115.html?_ga=1.11209399.200594361.1438696162

Answer (score 1):

"Einkaufswelten" are called "Shopping Worlds" in Shopware and there is an english tutorial right here:

http://community.shopware.com/Experienced-creating-Shopping-World-elements_detail_1668.html

It's for version 4.2 and above and should also work with 5.x. I've created my widget with help of that tutorial for Shopware 5.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look here:

https://developers.shopware.com/designers-guide/configuration-using-theme-php/

In Shopware you can create custom Theme Options - Is this what you are searching for?

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not what I'm looking for :(

Comment: I updated my answer - is this what you are searching for?